# Unable to release memory DC

Tags: c++, winapi

This is a program I made to open BMP pictures. When I need to open a new file, I need to clear the memory loaded last time, but it always fails. I don’t know where the mistake is.

```
static BYTE *data;
HDC memDC, winDC;
HBITMAP hBit;
HANDLE hFile;
if (data != NULL) {
  DeleteObject(hBit);

  ReleaseDC(hWnd, memDC); // faild,Invalid DC
  DWORD dwError = GetLastError();
  FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
                NULL, dwError, 0, szBuffer, 255, NULL);
  // DeleteDC(memDC);
  DeleteObject(memDC);
  \\Although the return value indicates success,
      the data memory cannot be released and an exception will be generated
          DWORD dd = GetLastError();
  ReleaseDC(hWnd, winDC);
  dd = GetLastError();

  int ss = ReleaseDC(hWnd, memDC);
  free(data); //产生异常
}
szFile = OpenBmp(hWnd);
if (szFile != NULL) {
  wcscpy_s(fName, lstrlen(szFile) * 2, szFile);
} else
  return NULL;
hFile = CreateFile(fName, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING,
                   FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
R = ReadFile(hFile, &bfh, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), &num, NULL);
if (R) {
  R = ReadFile(hFile, &fif, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), &num, NULL);
  winDC = GetDC(hWnd);
  memDC = CreateCompatibleDC(winDC);
  GetClientRect(hWnd, &rect);
  dataSize = bfh.bfSize - bfh.bfOffBits;
  data = (BYTE *)malloc(dataSize);

  pbmi.bmiHeader = fif;
  width = fif.biWidth;
  height = fif.biHeight;

  hBit =
      CreateDIBSection(memDC, &pbmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS, (void **)&data, NULL, 0);
  R = ReadFile(hFile, data, dataSize, &num, NULL);
  SelectObject(memDC, hBit);
  open = TRUE;
  InvalidateRect(hWnd, &rect, TRUE);
}
CloseHandle(hFile);
```

This is a program I made to open BMP pictures. When I need to open a new file, I need to clear the memory loaded last time, but it always fails. I don’t know where the mistake is.

Comment: Please be more specific than "it always fails". (BTW: you should not `GetLastError()` unless the most recent function call indicated that there *was* an error. Most functions don't clear the "last error" when they succeed.)

Comment: If that is your actual code, you're using quite a few uninitialized variables. Are you expecting the values of these to be restored the next time you call the function?

Comment: compiler hint 0xC0000005: Read location 0x0000029056CAFFF8

Comment: You seem to be expecting the non-static variables to retain their values between function calls. They don't.

Comment: The error checking is all wrong, GDI functions do not set the last error so calling GetLastError() is not correct.  The memory leak exists in the malloc() call, CreateDibSection overwrites `data` and the subsequent `free(data)` call is doomed to fail.  Do not call malloc, do not call free.  Memory is managed by GDI, DeleteObject() is sufficient to release the storage.

Comment: Although I agree with your point of view very much, I also guess that the memory is managed by GID and cannot be released manually, but when I only use DeleteObject（）, the memory cannot be released, because each of my pictures is 10M, and every time I open it, the memory The overhead will increase by 10M without release. So I had to find a way to free() the memory manually.

Comment: A very thorough read of [device contexts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/device-contexts) is in order. Probably a book, too. Get Petzold's.

Comment: P.S.: The [wicviewergdi](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/main/Samples/Win7Samples/multimedia/wic/wicviewergdi) sample shows a robust implementation of an image viewer. It's using the WIC so that you don't have to write your own image reader (and ship exploitable bugs along the way).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ReleaseDC(hWnd, memDC)` fails because you did not obtain `memDC` from `hWnd` in the first place, you obtained it from `CreateCompatibleDC()` instead, so you need to pass `memDC` to `DeleteDC()` (not `DeleteObject()`).

You obtained `winDC` from `hWnd`, so `winDC` is the DC that you need to pass to `ReleaseDC()`.

Also, you are selecting `hBit` into `memDC`, but you are not unselecting `hBit` before deleting them both.

Also, you are leaking memory, because `CreateDIBSection()` overwrites your `data` pointer with its own memory pointer, thus losing the address of your `malloc`'d memory.  You cannot use pre-allocated memory with `CreateDIBSection()` when its `hSection` parameter is NULL.

Aside from that, GDI functions do not use `GetLastError()` for error reporting.  And you are using `wcscpy_s()` incorrectly.

Try something more like this:

```
static BYTE *data = NULL;

HDC memDC = NULL, winDC = NULL;
HBITMAP hBit = NULL, hOldBit = NULL;
HANDLE hFile = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;

...

if (data) {
  data = NULL;
  SelectObject(memDC, hOldBit); hOldBit = NULL;
  DeleteObject(hBit); hBit = NULL;
  DeleteDC(memDC); memDC = NULL;
  ReleaseDC(hWnd, winDC); winDC = NULL;
}

szFile = OpenBmp(hWnd);
if (szFile == NULL) {
  return NULL;
}

wcscpy_s(fName, _countof(wcscpy_s), szFile);
hFile = CreateFile(fName, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
  return NULL;
}

R = (ReadFile(hFile, &bfh, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), &num, NULL) && (num == sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER)));
if (R) {
    R = (ReadFile(hFile, &fif, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), &num, NULL) && (num == sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER)));
}
if (R) {
  GetClientRect(hWnd, &rect);

  winDC = GetDC(hWnd);
  memDC = CreateCompatibleDC(winDC);

  pbmi.bmiHeader = fif;
  width = fif.biWidth;
  height = fif.biHeight;

  hBit = CreateDIBSection(memDC, &pbmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS, (void**)&data, NULL, 0);
  if (!hBit) {
    data = NULL;
    DeleteDC(memDC); memDC = NULL;
    ReleaseDC(hWnd, winDC); winDC = NULL;
    CloseHandle(hFile);
    return NULL;
  }

  dataSize = bfh.bfSize - bfh.bfOffBits;

  R = (ReadFile(hFile, data, dataSize, &num, NULL) && (num == dataSize));

  hOldBit = (HBITMAP) SelectObject(memDC, hBit);

  open = TRUE;
  InvalidateRect(hWnd, &rect, TRUE);
}

CloseHandle(hFile);
```